# Bluetooth not detecting any devices, UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I'v recently switched to using ubuntu and it doesn't detect my audio bluetooth receiver. Iv already cross checked and my phone detects it.

Output of     `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [103c:1785]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:311d Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b372 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
   [    3.317791] usb 2-1.6: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
   [    4.594641] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
   [    4.594657] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager    initialized
   [    4.594661] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
   [    4.594664] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
   [    4.594669] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
   [    5.130660] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
   [    5.130664] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
   [    5.130670] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
   [    6.285541] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
   [    6.285549] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
   [    6.285554] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
   [   30.845953] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1005 tx timeout
   [   32.850878] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c23 tx timeout
   [   34.855817] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
   [   36.875880] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c25 tx timeout
   [   38.893654] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
```

Output of `dmesg | grep ath3k; dkms status`

```
[    4.610954] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
```

Kernel Version is: 4.4.0-28-generic

My phone detects my pc but not the other way round. (that is the only other bluetooth device i have)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: The `0cf3:311d Atheros Communications, Inc. ` device is supported. Does it detect any other devices?

Comment: added to the post.

Comment: I mean does Ubuntu detect any other bluetooth devices? And please also add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: it doesnt. added the output to the post

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep ath3k; dkms status`.

Comment: added, dkms wasnt installed so had to install it. (also tried the bluetooth after the install). still not working.

Comment: And what is the kernel version? This looks like a kernel bug. I suggest reporting it by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. And also I suggest testing mainline kernels, like 4.7rc7 from mainline PPA. Anyway you will be asked to do it after you report the bug.

Comment: added, thank you for the help ! time to switch to windows i guess

Comment: 4.4.0-28 is not the latest. Update your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: still got the same issue with the new kernel